# FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE #0 php5 apache2.2, not loading extensions, cli it works fine

Tags: php, apache, freebsd, mbstring

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

It shows  `mbstring` being loaded if I run php index.php from console.

But if I load it from a website (Apache 2.2) it does not load `mbstring`.

Apache 2.2 configure `www:www` as the `user:group`.

I reinstalled Apache 2.2, PHP, PHP5-exensions, mod_php5 php5 many times, and still see the same issue. Tried apache24 php55 as well, same issue.

Had no problem when I was running Freebsd 8.

---

```
 /usr/local/etc/php 1164$ cat extensions.ini
extension=bz2.so
extension=hash.so
extension=phar.so
extension=zip.so
extension=zlib.so
extension=iconv.so
extension=mbstring.so
extension=dba.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=simplexml.so
extension=session.so
extension=gd.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=calendar.so
extension=ctype.so
extension=curl.so
extension=dom.so
extension=fileinfo.so
extension=filter.so
extension=ftp.so
extension=gmp.so
extension=json.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=openssl.so
extension=pcntl.so
extension=pdf.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=posix.so
extension=sqlite3.so
extension=tidy.so
extension=tokenizer.so
extension=xml.so
extension=xmlreader.so
extension=xmlwriter.so
```

Comment: Yes, I installed portmaster converters/php5-mbstring       PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in /usr/local/www/apache22/data/index.php on line 4

Comment: php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDFlib
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tidy
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

Comment: apache and cli are using the same php.ini.

Comment: http://71.174.98.35/ind.php   check the apache php info output

Comment: I spent 2 days on this already. I checked everything I could google. Very strange issue.

Comment: CLI was compiled with ZTS (Zend Thread Safety) when Apache module was not, or vice versa? Make sure to have the same value for this option for both ports (www/mod_php5(5) and lang/php5(5)).